# Unable to read key value pair from hashtable

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a specflow to test a service. I am reading the table and storing the key,values in a hashtable.

Here is a sample of the Feature file:

```
    |Index|Id | Message|
    |test1|1   | aa|
    |test2|2   | bb |
```

Here is how I read data from the table

```
    public Hashtable GetData(Table table)
    {
        var data = table.CreateSet<SpecFlowData>();
        var hashtable = new Hashtable();

        foreach (var currentRow in data)
        {
            var key = currentRow.Index;
            var value = GetValues(currentRow);
            hashtable.Add(key, value);

        }
        return hashtable;
    }
```

Here I am trying to extract the key and value pair in the hashtable

```
     [When(@"the test data is submitted to service")]
    public void WhenTheTestDataIsSubmittedService()
    {
    // the table data is now stored in a Textcontext
        var message = TestContext.Messages;
        byte? result = null;

        foreach (Hashtable entry in message)
        {
            var values = entry.Values;
            // problem area
            foreach (Hashtable item in  values)
            {
            var Ids = item["id"];
            var messages = item["message"];

            // send message to service accepts string,string input
            sendMessageResult = client.SendMessageToService((string)appIds, (string)messages);
            }

        }


    }
```

Since all the values have their own key value pair ..I tried to access it in the second loop but it is not looping the collection of the hashtable values.

I don't understand why I can't loop all the value collections in the second loop

Comment: This looks like a much harder version of Dictionary.

Comment: You should use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, not HashTable.

Comment: are you sure entry is of Type `Hashtable`?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 its ICollection

Comment: @SLaks your comment helped .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once I replace the Hashtable to Dictionary I am able to access data.